# How to export single calendar entries in Thunderbird?

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird, ics

Thunderbird can only export complete calendars as `*.ics` files, but I want to export only a **SINGLE** event for later sharing with an E-Mail. I explicity do not want to sent invitations, because the behaviour is very different on many E-Mail clients. Furthermore client-side invitations do not work reliably in Thunderbird, either.

*This is not a duplicate question.*

Comment: There is a post in the linked answer that does answer your question and answer it correctly. We do not require that the accepted answer be the one you're looking for, but that one of the posts there have the answer, which it does.